# log4j AbstractFilter.equals() appears to do Object identity equals

Tags: java, log4j2

Recently updated log4j from 2.1 to 2.2 and one of our tests fail that compares two Filters. It seems that the reason is that the old one checks (eventually) if a couple of the filters' ivars match in AbstractFilter (after going through AbstractLifeCycle equals method) but in the new version AbstractLifeCycle doesn't have an equals() so it goes to Object.equals() which of course fails for different instances.

Did I miss doing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We deliberately removed the equals implementation from AbstractLifeCycle since the superclass cannot know what equality means for all subclasses. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-891 for details.

Subclasses should implement equals() and hashCode() themselves. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok thank you - so is the equals() implementation in AbstractFilter broken now then? Is a bug report required for that?